# Los eventos de los controles no causan Postback en Firefox

Tags: asp.net, webforms

La misma página funciona correctamente en IE y Chrome.

```
<button id="BCrearB" type="button" class="button-green" title="Construye una encuesta nueva" onclick="DoPostBack('BCrearB');">
  <img src="/NuevaEncuesta.png">
  <span id="NuevaEnc">Nueva encuesta</span>
</button>
```

La función DoPostBack utliza métodos AJAX y se encarga de hacer algunas comprobaciones para luego llamar a la función __doPostBack() de ASP.NET

```
    function DoPostBack(Boton)
{
    TMisEncuestas.DoPostBack(Boton, SL, CallBackDoPostBack);
}

function CallBackDoPostBack(Resultado)
{
    if (Resultado.value) 
    {
        if (Resultado.value[4])
        {
            Compartir(Resultado.value[4]);
        }
        else if (Resultado.value[3])
        {
            CopiarMover(Resultado.value[3]);
        }
        else if (Resultado.value[2])
        {
            Aviso(Resultado.value[2])
        }
        else
        {
            ESDoPostBack(Resultado.value[0], Resultado.value[1]);     
        }
    }
}

function ESDoPostBack(Boton, Parametro) {
    $("#TAJAXUtil_Espere").espere("enable");
    __doPostBack(Boton, Parametro);
}


var theForm = document.forms['form'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

El __doPostBack envía la petición al OnLoad de la página, En el code-behind del webform se pregunta por **la propiedad Page.isPostback, en IE y Chrome es "true", en Firefox es "false"**.

Lo mismo ocurre con webcontrols que tiene asignado los eventos desde el código.

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl109" value="Pregunta (+)" title="Pulsa para añadir una pregunta al final de la página 1" class="Boton">
```

No consigo entender porque para Firefox los submit que lanzan estos controles no son Postback.

¿Alguien me ayuda por favor?

*EDITO añadiendo el código javascript, pero insisto en que el problema no está ahí, ya que el input hace un SUBMIT, no un __doPostBack y pasa exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Podrías [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/58538/edit) e incluir el código de la función `DoPostBack` para saber de que manera estás utilizando el `__doPostBack`.

Comment: Hola Anibal, si has podido solucionar tu problema te invito a que publiques una nueva respuesta ya que a diferencia de los foros [es.so] no permite poner soluciones directamente en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

He encontrado el problema.

Mi aplicación utiliza un HttpModule para gestionar las URL decoradas. Este HttpModule, según el caso que se le presente, ejecuta un RewritePath o un ServerTransfer para redirigir la Request del cliente.

El problema estaba en el ServerTransfer, ya que solo estaba indicando el parámetro Path, y tuve que añadir el parametro preseveForm con valor "true".